# Python using more than 1 thread

Tags: python

I used the below code:

```
import time


def create_square(num):
    time.sleep(5)
    return num * num


create_square(12)
create_square(12)
create_square(12)
```

In task manager, why does it show 4 threads ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shows how many threads your interpreter has, not how many threads are there in your code.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your answer, why does the interpreter needs 4 threads ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with python interpreter's code to tell you anything smarter other than the number of threads you see in process manager is the number of threads interpreter uses. If you want more detailed answer you'll have to dig into cpython.